# Issue with assigning the Discord role in PHP Script

Tags: php, wordpress, discord

I'm working on a WordPress plugin that can connect your WordPress site to Discord. After the user signs up using the shortcode, a role will automatically be assigned based on their current WordPress role. So far, everything is going well, but I've run into the following issue. Is there anyone who can assist me?

I'm sending the following data in the PUT request. The Discord bot has administrator rights and should assign a "low" role to the user.

```
[17-Sep-2023 10:49:52 UTC] Access token:
[17-Sep-2023 10:49:52 UTC] Discord User ID:
[17-Sep-2023 10:49:52 UTC] Server ID:
[17-Sep-2023 10:49:52 UTC] Bot Token:
[17-Sep-2023 10:49:52 UTC] Discord Role ID:
[17-Sep-2023 10:49:53 UTC] API Response: {
"message": "Missing Permissions",
"code": 50013
}
[17-Sep-2023 10:49:53 UTC] Received HTTP response code: 403
[17-Sep-2023 10:49:53 UTC] Received 403 from Discord API
[17-Sep-2023 10:49:53 UTC] Error assigning Discord role: Received 403 from Discord API
```

```
Here's the format of the API REQUEST:
Curl URL: https://discord.com/api/v8/guilds/%7B{SERVER ID}/members/{DISCORD USER ID}
Curl Headers: ["Authorization: Bot {BOT ID}","Content-Type: application/json"]
Curl Body: {"access_token":"{ACCESS_TOKEN}","roles":["{NEW ROLE ID}"]}
```

Below is the script for the function. Any data defined in another function/script has been successfully functioning in previous tests.

```
function assign_discord_role($access_token, $stored_discord_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    // Private data
    $bot_token = "MY PRIVATE BOT TOKEN HERE";
    $server_id = "MY SERVER ID HERE";

    // Retrieve the saved Discord ID and WordPress role
    $stored_discord_id = get_option('stored_discord_id');
    $stored_wp_role = get_option('current_wp_role');

    if (!$stored_discord_id) {
        error_log("Discord ID niet gevonden in WordPress-opties");
        return ['error' => 'Discord ID not found'];
    }

    // Log data for diagnostic purposes
    error_log("Function assign_discord_role is being invoked.");
    error_log("Assigning Discord role to Discord user ID: {$stored_discord_id}");
    error_log("Discord ID from WordPress options: {$stored_discord_id}");
    error_log("Access token: {$access_token}");
    error_log("Current WP role from WordPress options: {$stored_wp_role}");

    // Search the database for the corresponding Discord role
    $query = "SELECT discord_role_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}discord_role_mappings WHERE wp_role = %s";
    $discord_role_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($query, $stored_wp_role));
    error_log("Discord role ID from DB: {$discord_role_id}");

    if (!$discord_role_id) {
        error_log("No corresponding Discord role found for WordPress role.");
        return ['error' => 'No corresponding Discord role found'];
    }

    // Log the data to be sent
    error_log("API Request Data:");
    error_log("Discord User ID: " . $stored_discord_id);
    error_log("Server ID: " . $server_id);
    error_log("Bot Token: " . $bot_token);
    error_log("Discord Role ID: " . $discord_role_id);

    $url = "https://discord.com/api/v8/guilds/{$server_id}/members/{$stored_discord_id}";
    $headers = [
        "Authorization: Bot {$bot_token}",
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ];

    $body = json_encode([
        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'roles' => [$discord_role_id]
    ]);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
    
    // Log the exact API request being sent
    error_log("Curl URL: {$url}");
    error_log("Curl Headers: " . json_encode($headers));
    error_log("Curl Body: {$body}");
    error_log("API Response: " . json_encode(json_decode($curl_response), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));


    if ($curl_response === false) {
        error_log("Something went wrong while contacting Discord API: " . curl_error($ch));
        return ['error' => "Something went wrong: " . curl_error($ch)];
    }

    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    error_log("Received HTTP response code: {$http_code}");

    if ($http_code === 200 || $http_code === 201 || $http_code === 204) {
        error_log("Successfully assigned Discord role: {$discord_role_id}");
        return ['success' => $discord_role_id];
    } else {
        error_log("Received {$http_code} from Discord API");
        return ['error' => "Received $http_code from Discord API"];
    }

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

I have added extensive logging to check User ID, Server ID, Discord Role ID, and Bot Token. All of these are correct. Furthermore, I have also verified the scopes and, of course, the bot permissions...

Comment: You should check for `50013` in the Discord API. It looks like the bot does not have the permissions.

Comment: I understand what the error means; however, the bot has administrator rights. And the scopes have been assigned... It seems to be an issue with the script, but I really can't find the problem.

Comment: Your URL does not look the same. The example says: `Curl URL: https://discord.com/api/v8/guilds/%7B{SERVER ID}/members/{DISCORD USER ID}
`.  The `%7B` after `guilds/` is missing.

Comment: Tipp: you can simplify `($http_code === 200 || $http_code === 201 || $http_code === 204)` to `in_array($http_code, [200, 201, 204], true)`.

Comment: I double-checked it, I see what you mean, but unfortunately, this issue is not the problem... I also tried changing it to V10; however, this had no effect...

`Curl URL: https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/{GUILD ID}/members/{DISCORD USER ID}`

Comment: Perhaps interestingly, if I assign a role that doesn't exist, there is no error, and the API provides a success message (of course, no role is actually assigned because it doesn't exist...)

Comment: In the v10 URL the `%7B` is also missing.

Comment: I apologize, I don't understand that, adding %7B to the URL as you mentioned would not be correct and would most likely result in an error from the Discord API. Correct me if I'm wrong... But then I'm very curious about how you mean the entire URL.

Comment: Read again my previous comment. :) https://ibb.co/xL5DnkY

Comment: As I indicated this one I don't understand.... but I tried it with the result below. 

`[17-Sep-2023 18:26:12 UTC] API Response: {
    "message": "Invalid Form Body",
    "code": 50035,
    "errors": {
        "guild_id": {
            "_errors": [
                {
                    "code": "NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE",
                    "message": "Value \"{1147580235466944614\" is not snowflake."
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}`

Comment: That's why I put the picture in. The error from the picture gives you the URL format. But your code is not that format. *COMPARE THE URL* https://ibb.co/G2PrVcP

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but what you're saying, that can't be right, can it? I've performed that, but please take a look at the attachment... https://ibb.co/2WMxhYD

Comment: The error now says: `Value/User is not a snowflake.` Different error, different problem. When I look at the body you are **not** sending a `user_id`.

Comment: Markus, that's correct, and it makes sense. The %7B is replacing the { for SERVER_ID. Since it results in a server id that doesn't exist, this error occurs... So it's true that it's a different error and a different problem, but that's because the server id with { doesn't exist...

Comment: `%7B` is not a replacement, it is a **prefix** when I look at the message. It comes **before** the `{SERVER ID}` not **as**.